# How to log execution time of procedure in oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I want to log execution time of every procedure in oracle DB 11g/12c on very execution.

Columns Required

1. Procedure Name
2. Object Owner
3. Execution Start Time
4. Execution End Time

Comment: You need to write a logging framework - or download [Logger from github](https://github.com/OraOpenSource/Logger) - then write calls to the framework in the start and end of every procedure. If that seems like a lot of work (and if you have an existing codebase it is) consider whether [profiling solves the problem you're trying to solve](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_profiler.htm#CHDJEGIA).

Comment: @APC Thanks for your comment. Really Helpful. It is very tedious task to change every procedure. Can you please suggest if AUDIT in Oracle DB will help.

Comment: You can use DBMS_PROFILER. Refer the link  - https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/dbms_profiler

Comment: You can use AUDIT EXECUTE to track who called a procedure (or whatever) and what time they executed the call i.e. 3.Execution Start Time. It won't tell you how long the call lasted (so no 3.Execution End Time). So whether that helps depends on what you're actually trying to achieve.